# How can I make my sum accurate each time I run the program?

Tags: java

This is part of my code for a Black Jack program that I broke apart. This is just the section that deals two cards to the player and then prompts for another card and totals up the sum. My sum messes up every time when the player chooses another card, because my formula will add the new number to the original two cards and now the first two cards and the first new card.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class DealToPlayer 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String input;
        char choice; 
        int sum; 
        int card1; 
        int card2; 
        int newCard;  

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

        Random randomNumbers = new Random(); 

        card1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(13)+1; 
        card2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(13)+1; 

        System.out.println("First Card: " +card1 + " Second Card: " +card2); 

        System.out.println("Would you like another card?"); 
        input = keyboard.nextLine(); 
        choice = input.charAt(0); 

        do 
        {
            newCard = randomNumbers.nextInt(13)+1; 
            System.out.println("New card: " +newCard); 

            sum = card1 + card2 + newCard; 
            System.out.println("Sum: " +sum); 

            System.out.println("Would you like another card?"); 
            input = keyboard.nextLine(); 
            choice = input.charAt(0); 

        }while (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y'); 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

just extract the *card1 + card2* from the loop :

```
sum = card1 + card2;
do 
{
    newCard = randomNumbers.nextInt(13)+1; 
    System.out.println("New card: " +newCard); 

    sum = sum + newCard; 
    System.out.println("Sum: " +sum);
```

this way each loop will add only the new card value to the sum.

Comment: Better yet, `int sum = card1 + card2;`